# Is it possible to style a text input to fill the width of it's parent?

Tags: css, width, textinput

I have had this issue for years and I've seen similar questions before, but none of them have addressed the fact that when setting `width: 100%` on an element - paddings, margins and borders will *increase* the width.

---

Have a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfUre/6/).

The white topmost text box is a standard text box with it's width set to `100%`. As you can see it overflows it's parent because of the margin, padding and border settings.

The green text box is styled like a div using `position: absolute`. This works like a dream in webkit browsers but nowhere else.

The red div is the control - I want the input to act **just like that**.

---

Are there any hacks/tricks I can employ to have my text inputs act just like the red div in all modern browsers, in other words, fit inside the padding of the parent? Please edit my Fiddle or create your own to accompany your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can:

```css
input#classic
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;        
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qfUre/17/).

Note I removed the `margin`, since that was causing an overflow, and set the `box-sizing` to determine the width of the element *including* the width of the borders and padding.

Comment: When I fake the margin using the parent's padding property this is actually a [completely viable solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/qfUre/29/). +1 Thanks for the answer

Comment: this answer should have more thumbs up! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Using `calc` to compensate for the margin and `box-sizing` for the padding

```css
input#classic
{
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 10px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 10px);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/qfUre/31/)

Comment: This seems like the ***correct*** solution, but unfortunately [browser support is still lacking](http://caniuse.com/calc). Also your example doesn't work in FireFox for some reason.

Comment: Too bad it's not supported in Opera though

Answer (score 0):

Try with  `display:table-cell` property

```
  display:table;
  display:table-cell;
```

may it help you

please check this link

[Style input element to fill remaining width of its container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773517/style-input-element-to-fill-remaining-width-of-its-container)