# How do Flex boxes work?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is my code that I am using but I am trying to understand what is happening not just what lines to type. In `display: -webkit-flex`, is this to load what flex is as its not a standard attribute? Is there a universal way on loading these originally or is it standard to do this for each attribute you use. Also is this proper for what I am trying to create? (A inline navigation bar aligned to the right side)

```css
.nav-flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify: flex-end;
  max-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-flex-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-flex-item"><a href="web-development.html">Web Development</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-flex-item"><a href="climbing.html">Climbing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-flex-item"><a href="about-me.html">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-flex-item"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you asking what a vendor prefix is? Your question is unclear.

Comment: if you are trying to make a column nav bar down the right side of the page, it certainly appears you have succeeded

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Unfortunately, "how" questions don't usually work out too well.  It would be better if you could rephrase it to "why doesn't this work", but it appears you mostly have it working.  This leaves us not quite sure what you're wanting.  (And for future reference, we generally don't put tags in the titles, so I've edited that out.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox is a recent addition to CSS. Then, the specification is not stable enough, so some browsers use vendor prefixes before the standard property or value. For example, webkit-based browsers use `display: -webkit-flex` or `-webkit-justify-content`.

If you want to make every element a flex container (I don't recommend it), you can use

```css
* {
  display: flex;
  /* Repeat the same but with vendor prefixes */
}
```

And no, you are not using it correctly. [Only children become flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14148162/1529630). So the flex container should be the `ul`:

```css
.nav-flex-container > ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-flex-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-flex-item"><a href="web-development.html">Web Development</a></li>
    <li class="nav-flex-item"><a href="climbing.html">Climbing</a></li>
    <li class="nav-flex-item"><a href="about-me.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li class="nav-flex-item"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: How is flex-box a recent addition? It's been around since 2007!

Comment: @GustvandeWal Maybe I didn't choose the most appropriate words. I meant that the spec is still a working draft, so it's still considered experimental. In fact, the syntax has changed considerably since the first proposals.

Comment: I have to say that only recently it has become something so useful that people prefer it over - for example - floating elements, that is true.

Answer (score 0):

Flex box is a new way to do layouts, align items, organize spaces etc. I usually use flex to help me in layouts that need align vertically items for example.
But has an excelent complete guide in [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) that can help you with those doubts.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure precisely what you are asking but your layout method should be:

```css
.nav-flex-container ul {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify: flex-end;
  max-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-flex-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-flex-item"><a href="web-development.html">Web Development</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-flex-item"><a href="climbing.html">Climbing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-flex-item"><a href="about-me.html">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-flex-item"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```