# css: let input field fill the space left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to let a label and an input field fill the whole width of a from. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/x8q8Q/) is my attempt. This is the HTML

```
<form>
    <p>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input/>
    </p>
</form>
```

and CSS

```
form {
    widht: 400px height: 500px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
label {
    float: left;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

When I put a with: 100% in the input field it moves below the label and without the width it is too small. Any suggestions ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Style input element to fill remaining width of its container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773517/style-input-element-to-fill-remaining-width-of-its-container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a wrapper element around your `input` and set `overflow: hidden;` (Make sure you use a `block` level element, if you are using `span` than declare `display: block;` in your CSS)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sVK9k/)

```
<label>Blah Blah</label>
<div><input type="text" /></div>

label {
    float: left;
}
div {
    overflow: hidden;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to set `width` attribute properly.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x8q8Q/10/)**

```
label {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
}
input {
    width: 83%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Minimize the fiddle window :)

Comment: on that case, you have to make it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

If you firebug it, you will know that Your border is actually putting some padding to the container p. So, if you just put border to none then you will be good to do.
If you want to use border and dont want the input to go outside the form, then you need to either shorten the width of the input a little and apply border or you give some padding to your form.

Try This CSS

```
form {
 background-color: #D3D3D3;
 height: 500px;
 width: 400px;
}
form p{
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
label {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
input {
 border:0;
 float: left;
 height: 20px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/awaise17/x8q8Q/12/)