# Input fill the remaining space

Tags: css

I have that code:

```
<form class="choose-game" action="?" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <select name="game" id="game" required>
            <option value="battlefield 4">Battlefield 4</option>
            <option value="call of duty ghosts">Call Of Duty: Ghosts</option>
            <option value="fifa 2014">FIFA 2014</option>
            <option value="league of legends">League of Legends</option>
            <option value="need for speed rivals">Need For Speed: Rivals</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Wybierz">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2BDy/), but I want to input fill the remaining space in fieldset (except interstice). Any other one solution from StackOverflow doesn't work. What I must to do?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19022840/1542290)?

Comment: Yes, but I can't modify my code into that. Maybe it can't work by the fact that in my fill with this is on the left.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883998/css-stretch-textbox-to-fill-remaining-space
should be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay with setting the width of the select box to a percentage you can then have the input fill the remaining width. You will also have to float the input and select to the left.

Try modifying the .choose-game select and input properties like this

```
.choose-game select { width:20%; float:left }

.choose-game input[type="submit"] { 
    background-color: #3498db; color: #fff; cursor:   pointer; width:80%; float:left;
}
```