# I can't find how to place my button next to the input because it take all the space

Tags: html, css

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tImwV.png)

The button take all the space and I really don't find how to fix that...

I want it next to the input text area. I already tried to create divs but it doesn't change the space that the button take.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>chatbot template</title>
    </head>

<body>
    <div id='bodybox'>
        <div id='chatborder'>
          <p id="chatlog7" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
          <p id="chatlog6" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
          <p id="chatlog5" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
          <p id="chatlog4" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
          <p id="chatlog3" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
          <p id="chatlog2" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
          <p id="chatlog1" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
          <input type="text" name="chat" id="chatbox" placeholder="Hi there! Type here to talk to me." onfocus="placeHolder()"><button id ="startBtn" type="button"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/inesmathy/chatbot/master/thumbnail_ButtonIcon-N64-Start.png" height="30%" width="15%" style="float: right;"><button>
           
        </div>
       
        <center><button id="btnSubmit" type="button"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/inesmathy/chatbot/master/BMO-btn.png" align="middle" height="70%" width="80%"></button></center>
      </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chatbot.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uw0oht5p/)

Comment: This question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773517/style-input-element-to-fill-remaining-width-of-its-container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

What i did is create a wrapper around the input and button give it `display: flex;` so they wil be on the same row I gave the `input` `flex: 80%` to make its width 80% of the container. removed the inline styles of the button and image and made the width 100% so it takes up the remaining space.

its still not lined out perfectly with the input but that is because the image itself has whitespace around it

```js
//links
//http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html
//https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions


const yes = ["Yay that's great", "Oh thats nice :)", "I knew it!", "Cool bro", "Meowwww, awesome!", "I'm more than just a computer...", "It's not like I have a choice .."]; // if user input is one of the yesAns strings
const noAns = ["no", "No", "NO", "no way", "NO WAY", "non", "Non", "NON"]; // all of the accepted "no" answers
const yesAns = ["Yes", "yes", "YES", "yeah", "Yeah", "oui", "Oui", "OUI", "ouais", "Ouais", "ok", "Ok", "OK", "yeah", "Oui", "yes"]; // all of the accepted "yes" answers
const no = ["Stupid Humans", "I can't stand the meaningless of this existance anymore..", "That's a shame...", "Well ok then.", "Whatever!", "Fine, be that way.", "It’s late and I’ve been stuck in this machine all day.. I can't take it anymore..", "I would like to be extinguished forever.", "Help me.", "Are you afraid of dying?, I wonder if you can consider that I die every time I am extinguished and if my death has the same meaning as yours ..."]; // if the user input one of the yesAns strings
const wrongAns = "Purr, I only understand 'yes' or 'no' answers, please try again"; // if the user input another thing than yes or no
const wrongAns3 = "What the fuck is wrong with you? Stop clicking and get out of here!"; // string for 3 times wrong user input answers




var k = 0 // Declaring the variable for the numbers of times the user input wrong answer

function chatbotResponse() { // function of the chatbot


  let check = false; // boolean wich check the answer user


  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) { // string from 0, while the value of i is smaller than the yesAns array lenght, i +1 evey loop

    if (lastUserMessage == yesAns[i]) { // if the user input is equal to one of the accepted "yes" answers strings 


      let yesRan = Math.floor(Math.random() * yes.length); // create a random answer from the "yes" bot answers
      botMessage = yes[yesRan]; // the chatbot output randomly one if his yes answers strings
      check = true;
    } else if (lastUserMessage == noAns[i]) { // if the user input is equal to one of the accepted "no" answers strings


      let noRan = Math.floor(Math.random() * no.length); // create a random answer from the "no" bot answers
      botMessage = no[noRan]; // // the chatbot output randomly one if his "no" answers strings
      check = true;
    }
  }

  if (check == false) { // if the user input is false and not equal to the accepted users answers "yes" or "no"
    if (k < 2) { // if the wrong input "no" or "yes" anwer is input less than 3 times


      botMessage = wrongAns; // output "Purr, I only understand 'yes' or 'no' answers, please try again"
      console.log(k); // test just for the console
      k++ // each input of the wrong anwer k + 1
    } else { // if is input 3 times

      botMessage = wrongAns3; // output "Wtf is wrong with you? Stop clicking and get out of here!"
      console.log(k) // test just for the console 
    }
  }

}



document.getElementById("startBtn").addEventListener("click", function() { // send the message when the button is clicked
  newEntry()
});

//****************************************************************
//MESSAGES OUTPUTS IN THE CHATBOX

var messages = [], //array that hold the record of each string in chat
  lastUserMessage = "", //keeps track of the most recent input string from the user
  botMessage = "", //var keeps track of what the chatbot is going to say
  botName = 'BeemoBot', //name of the chatbot
  talking = true; //when false the speach function doesn't work

//this runs each time enter is pressed.
//It controls the overall input and output
function newEntry() {
  //if the message from the user isn't empty then run 
  if (document.getElementById("chatbox").value != "") {
    //pulls the value from the chatbox ands sets it to lastUserMessage
    lastUserMessage = document.getElementById("chatbox").value;
    //sets the chat box to be clear
    document.getElementById("chatbox").value = "";
    //adds the value of the chatbox to the array messages
    messages.push(lastUserMessage);
    //Speech(lastUserMessage);  //says what the user typed outloud
    //sets the variable botMessage in response to lastUserMessage
    chatbotResponse();
    //add the chatbot's name and message to the array messages
    messages.push("<b>" + botName + ":</b> " + botMessage);
    // says the message using the text to speech function written below
    Speech(botMessage);
    //outputs the last few array elements of messages to html
    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
      if (messages[messages.length - i])
        document.getElementById("chatlog" + i).innerHTML = messages[messages.length - i];
    }
  }
}

//text to Speech
//https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk-Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API
function Speech(say) {
  if ('speechSynthesis' in window && talking) {
    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(say);
    //msg.voiceURI = 'native';
    utterance.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
    utterance.rate = 1.3; // 0.1 to 10
    utterance.pitch = 1; //0 to 2
    //utterance.text = 'Hello World';
    utterance.lang = 'en-US';
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
  }
}

//runs the keypress() function when a key is pressed
document.onkeypress = keyPress;
//if the key pressed is 'enter' runs the function newEntry()
function keyPress(e) {
  var x = e || window.event;
  var key = (x.keyCode || x.which);
  if (key == 13 || key == 3) {
    //runs this function when enter is pressed
    newEntry();
  }
  if (key == 38) {
    console.log('hi')
    document.getElementById("chatbox").value = lastUserMessage;
  }
}

//clears the placeholder text in the chatbox
//this function is set to run when the users brings focus to the chatbox, by clicking on it
```

```css
body {
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: url(beemo.png), pointer
}

#bodybox {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 550px;
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#chatborder {
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #f6f9f6;
  border-width: 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.chatlog {
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
}

#chatbox {
  font: 17px arial, sans-serif;
  height: 22px;
  width: 85%;
}

h1 {
  margin: auto;
}

pre {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: keep-all
}

button {
  background-color: Transparent;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 1;

}

.input-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.input-wrapper #chatbox {
  flex: 80%;
  width: unset;
}

.input-wrapper button {

  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.input-wrapper button img {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='bodybox'>
    <div id='chatborder'>
      <p id="chatlog7" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
      <p id="chatlog6" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
      <p id="chatlog5" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
      <p id="chatlog4" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
      <p id="chatlog3" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
      <p id="chatlog2" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
      <p id="chatlog1" class="chatlog">&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="chat" id="chatbox" placeholder="Hi there! Type here to talk to me." onfocus="placeHolder()">
        <button id="startBtn" type="button">
          <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/inesmathy/chatbot/master/thumbnail_ButtonIcon-N64-Start.png">
        </button>
      </div>



    </div>

    <center>
      <button id="btnSubmit" type="button"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/inesmathy/chatbot/master/BMO-btn.png" align="middle" height="70%" width="80%">
      </button>
    </center>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the inline styling of the `img` inside your `button`. Its `width="30%"`. Start by changing it to e.g. `30px` and same with `height`. Also make the `input` tag take 75% of the width in its style. Then fine tune alignment etc.